# Using Dependency walker to fix runtime error

Tags: dll, x86, 64-bit, pyinstaller, dependency-walker

I wrote an executable python program using `PyInstaller` but I am getting a runtime error:

[image: Error]

The app runs perfectly but it always has this error come up. I want to get rid of this problem.

I followed some advice from Stack Overflow and used dependency walker to find issues. In the log section I am getting output like this:

[image]

Where a bunch of .dll files have a *red x86* while `PyInstaller` has a *black x64*.  Does this have something to do with 32 bit and 64 bit CPUs? Do I need to update my .dll files to 64 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have opened a 64-bit executable with the 32-bit version of Dependency Walker.  If you re-open the file with the 64-bit version of Dependency walker it should get rid of your second error.  And should point you to your first error which is a missing MS CRT DLL.

Comment: Thanks.  where should I put the missing MS CRT dll.  I've looked around and it supposedly goes in the C:\Windows\winsxs but i don't have access to it.

Comment: You need to find the MS CRT redistribution package and install it.  That will put it in the correct locaiton.